# Acceder a las propiedades de un control en otro formulario en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un form1 (el menú principal) y dentro de éste tengo otros UserControls, (de esta forma cuando se clickea sobre un menú, superpongo un UserControl u otro) adjunto imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, quería hacer un modo día/noche, por lo que añadí el pequeño switch que se puede ver en la barra, este switch está úbicado en el form principal, de esta forma, si se hace click sobre él cambia el diseño a un modo día/noche.

Hasta aquí todo bien, el dataGridView está situado dentro del UserControl, por lo que no puedo acceder a las propiedades del datagridview desde el Form1.

¿Cómo podría acceder a las propiedades de los controles de los Usercontrol desde el form1 para poder así cambiar el diseño? Adjunto otra imagen para que se vea más claro...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Muchas gracias!

Pequeña aclaración: No es un segundo formulario, es un UserControl, (en la última imagen puse form2 y en verdad es un Usercontrol) puedo pasarme datos con setters/getters, pero no tengo ni la menor idea de como modificar las propiedades del DataGridView

Update:

Mi idea es poder filtrar el datagridview, en función de lo que se busque en un textbox, al principio cree el textbox en el usercontrol, de la siguiente forma.

```
        private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
            bs.Filter = dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        }
```

Y filtra bien, sin problema, por lo que decidí hacer un textbox en mi Form, y en el usercontrol crear un método al que llamaba desde el textbox del Form, quedando algo así:

En el user control:

```
        public void Busqueda(string str)
        {
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
            bs.Filter = dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + str + "%'";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        }
```

Y el form así:

```
        private void bunifuTextbox1_OnTextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inventario1.Busqueda(bunifuTextbox1.Text);
        }
```

Sin embargo, haciendo esto no consigo que filtre en absoluto. ¿A qué se debe?

Comment: Probaste lllamar a un metodo en tu UC que cambie las propriedades de la grilla?

Comment: Si creo un método dentro del UserControl no es accesible en el Form1, y si lo intento crear dentro del namespace pero fuera de la clase UserControl, la grilla no existe en ese contexto

Comment: Si lo pones publico no es accesible? porque?

Comment: Es accesible instanciando un objeto, por ejemplo UserControl ex = New UserControl(); Ex.Metodo(); de otra forma no puedo acceder a esa función/método desde el Form, y aún haciendolo así no surje ningún efecto sobre la grilla, te actualizaré el código arriba para que puedas ver lo que hice, quizá hice algo mal, no soy muy buena programando...

Comment: Hay un error ahi.. ese ss no es el control de tu form.. es un nuevo objeto que acabas de crear.. tenes que poner el control de tu form ahi... un control (cualquiera) o un form (cualquiera) no son mas que objetos comunes (con la salvedad que saben dibujarse), lo que tenes que hacer es llamar al metodo de tu control (asi como llamas por ejemplo a datagridview1.backgrondcolor)

Comment: Vale, efectivamente funcionó, pero ahora estoy teniendo otro pequeño problema por el cuál no se me actualiza el datagridview (editaré el post para que sea más fácil ayudarme) gracias!

Comment: y viene algo en str??

Comment: Vale, acabo de descubrir el motivo, por alguna razón los controles creados con bunifu, tienen la propiedad "Text" y "text", la primera por alguna razón no envia nada, (strings vacios...) la segunda funciona perfectamente. ¿Por qué demonios hay dos propiedades text? jaja

Comment: desconozco eso, si fuera un textbox comun no tendria dos propiedades text...